# Excel copying/with formula

Tags: microsoft-excel, mac

I'm using OFfice 365 on a Mac
I have one workbook with multiple sheets A B1 B2 B3 etc (up to about B15).
All the Bs are the same (identical).
A is where all the data gets summarised and analysed. 
I've set up A and B1 with all the linking between them.
Can I copy B1, rename it to B2 etc, and still keep the links between B2 and A? Or do I need to copy all the Bs I need, then individually update the functions/formulae feeding the data back to A?
Thanks!

Comment: Hi @Matt, it is more complex problem. You collect data in Sheet "A", so after copping another sheet you always must update links in it. If you offer some simple sample, I can answer more precisely.

Comment: No since `A1` & `B1` are linked so then Sheet Name matters,, may be you have used Formula in A1 with Sheet B1 referenced Cell /Cells or Paste as Link,, in both situations,, if the Sheet name varies you get `#Ref` error !!

Comment: Do you need to analyse each Bx sheet separately on A sheet, or you need to analyse all 15 Bx sheets in complex? If first then you may to have a cell in A which stores the sheet name which must be analysed, and all references to the sheet to be analysed may be relative to this sheet name, so you need to change only one cell for to switch to another sheet.

Comment: @Akina I think that sounds like a solution!? Each B sheet is summarised on A in different tables. So if there is some way to tell excel which sheet to refer to for each item in A that would be great!

Comment: *if there is some way to tell excel which sheet to refer to for each item in A* Function INDIRECT() allows to build cell address, including worksheet name, like `=INDIRECT("SheetB1!A1")`, so if destination sheet name is stored, for example, in A1, then you may use `=INDIRECT(A1&"!A1")` to refer to a cell A1 on the worksheet, which name is stored in A1 on current worksheet (if current A1="SheetB1" then we will obtain the address shown above literally). And change current sheet's A1 will point all such references to the worksheet of newly entered name.

Answer (score 0):

HowTo - example.

Create new workbook with 3 worksheets named Sheet1, Sheet2 and Sheet3.

Open Sheet2 and set A1:A3 to some values.

Open Sheet3 and set A1:A3 to some values different from that on Sheet2.

Open Sheet1 and set:

```
B1=Sheet2
A1=INDIRECT($B$1 & "!R" & ROW() & "C" & COLUMN(), FALSE)
```

or the same in VBA

```
cells(1,2).formula="Sheet2"
cells(1,1).formula="=INDIRECT($B$1 & ""!R"" & ROW() & ""C"" & COLUMN(), FALSE)"
```

You will see the data posessed in A1 on Sheet2.

Drag A1 over A1:A3. You will see the data posessed on Sheet2.

Edit B1 and set it ti "Sheet3". You will see the data posessed on Sheet3.

Using this method you may freely refer to any worksheet and alter all references to any another worksheet using simple sheet name change in the only cell. Of course you may use A1 style and literal address component values if needed.